# Accessing an open MDB file via PHP for many users

Tags: php, html, ms-access, web

I have a system that accesses an MDB file that contains time in/out information. This software is usually set running 24/7. How do I obtain the contents of an already open MDB file through the PHP, especially to many users? Do note that the system I'll be developing will not write to the MDB file, only read the table contents. Does MDB prevent concurrent connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MS Access MDB allows dozens of concurrent connections.**
The earliest versions allowed about 10 concurrent connections (Edit: concurrent Users. Please see the edit below), newer versions allow many more ([read more here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4462)).
In development, you should have in mind that **DB connections are resources, and should be used wisely**: Open the connection to read the data, close connection, do you work, open connection to save changes, close connection. That way you are expected to stay far from concurrent connections limits, as for network limitations too.

---

**EDIT**: The Link above refers to 10 concurrent **MS Access Users** linked to a single MDB file. Note that each MS Access MDB application (in Access terms: *Front end*) may hold dozens of opened connections (in Access terms: opened *Linkd-tables*, or *bound forms* to linked tables), to the MDB data file (in Access terms: *Back-End*). This SW architecture is quite inefficient, and may limit use of full MS Access system in a network environment.
**Systems using mdb files as a Data-Base, and use them efficiently, are mainly limited only to Data-Base size (2GB in Access 2000 and up).**
Please see [this link from MS MVP](http://forums.asp.net/post/2558700.aspx) about connecting to MDB file from another web environment.

Comment: thanks! I figured that doing the back-end/front-end splits should do the trick. I'll need to test it now. Unfortunately I'm not the creator of the other system and it's only limited to MDB.

Comment: you should always split your Access DB to [Preventing corruption](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-25.html)